# Configure solr's dataimport of docker container by enviroments variables

Tags: docker, solr, docker-compose

we need switch our solr to docker container. In data config of our cores we have configuration like this:

```
<dataSource type="JdbcDataSource"
            driver="org.postgresql.Driver"
            url="${dataimporter.request.db_url}"
            user="${dataimporter.request.db_user}"
            password="${dataimporter.request.db_pass}" />
```

and in solrconfig.xml

```
  <requestHandler name="/dataimport" class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="config">data-config.xml</str>
      <str name="db_url">@db.jdbcurl@</str>
      <str name="db_user">@db.username@</str>
      <str name="db_pass">@db.pass@</str>
    </lst>
  </requestHandler>
```

`@...@` variables were set from maven properties. Can you tell me how to pass values of `@...@` variables in docker compose file?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To solve this, I've prepared my own solr image and I added a special append.solr.sh that gets appended to `/opt/solr/bin/solr.in.sh`. The cores use the java properties I've defined in the append.solr.sh in the dataSource portion.

---

I've prepared an append.solr.sh file:

```
# Our specific configs.
EXTRA_OPTIONS="-Djava.system.database=$DB_TARGET -Djava.system.dbport=$DB_PORT -Djava.system.dbuser=$DB_USERNAME -Djava.system.dbpass=$DB_PASSWORD"
SOLR_OPTS="$SOLR_OPTS $EXTRA_OPTIONS"
```

```
FROM solr

EXPOSE 8983

USER root
COPY append.solr.sh /append.solr.sh
RUN cat /append.solr.sh >> /opt/solr/bin/solr.in.sh \
    && rm /append.solr.sh

COPY --chown=solr:solr cores /opt/solr/server/solr/mycores

USER solr

WORKDIR /opt/solr

ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["solr-foreground"]
```

Modified the dataSource for my cores like this:

```
<dataSource
    type="JdbcDataSource"
    driver="com.sap.db.jdbc.Driver"
    url="jdbc:sap://${java.system.database}:${java.system.dbport}"
    user="${java.system.dbuser}"
    password="${java.system.dbpass}" />
```

And changed my docker-compose.yml to look like this:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  search:
    image: mysolr:latest
    container_name: mysolr
    build:
      context: ./search
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      - DB_TARGET
      - DB_PORT
      - DB_USERNAME
      - DB_PASSWORD
```

Last, I generate a `.env` file containing those variables.

---

**EDIT** - alternative solution to match your setup:

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.6"
  services:
    postgres:
      image: postgres:11-alpine
      ports:
        - "5435:5432"
      environment:
        - POSTGRES_DB=${ENV_DB}
        - POSTGRES_USER=${ENV_PASS}
        - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${ENV_USER}
      volumes:
        - ./etc/db-init/ddl.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/1-ddl.sql
        - ./etc/db-init/dml.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/2-dml.sql
        - pg_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

    solr:
      build: ./etc/.
      ports:
        - "8983:8983"
      environment:
        - db_url=${ENV_JDBC}
        - db_user=${ENV_USER}
        - db_password=${ENV_PASS}
      volumes:
        - solr_data:/var/solr/data
      depends_on:
        - postgres
volumes:
  pg_data:
  solr_data:
```

.env

```
ENV_USER=os
ENV_PASS=heslo
ENV_DB=os
ENV_JDBC=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/os
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM solr:8.2
USER root
COPY pgdriver/postgresql-42.2.8.jar /opt/solr/dist/
COPY solr/ /opt/solr/server/solr/ 
CMD "/opt/solr/bin/solr start -Ddb_url=$db_url -Ddb_user=$db_user -Ddb_password=$db_password -s /opt/solr/server/solr -f -force"
```

Comment: Thank you I will try it and give you response. Can I ask where do you pass .env file into compose?

Comment: You don't need to pass it. It's an optional file that doesn't need to be defined in the `env_files` block since it also behaves differently. For clarity: the filename is actually `.env` and is in the same folder as the docker-compose.yml.

Comment: More info about it: https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#the-env-file

Comment: is required prefix `java.system.` ?

Comment: IIRC you can use whatever you want

Comment: I'm asking because I tried it but still not works. I got solr exception 

`Error loading solr config from /opt/solr/server/solr-shop/cores/category/conf/solrconfig.xml

No system property or default value specified for db_user value:${db_user}`

Comment: did you change the property name in the `append.solr.sh` file as well?

Comment: yes, I also rename this file, could this made problem? Now I also checking value of enviroments in container with command echo $var, and when I call `echo $VAR_FROM_COMPOSE` I got required value, but with `$Dvar_from_sh` I got nothing

Comment: I've tried to remove the `java.system.` prefix from my project and everything seems to work fine. When you say that you changed the filename, I assume you changed the `append.solr.sh`, the other one is supposed to remain as it is now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200722/discussion-between-stefano-and-denis-stephanov).

Comment: I've edited the answer with a different approach to the problem

Comment: I would like to thank you @Stefano because I was looking to do this for days now, and thanks to you I understood how the `solr.in.sh` works and how to make it work with environment variables

Answer (score 1):

You can access JVM system properties in the dataimport config file and the system properties can be set via the environment variable `SOLR_OPTS` as descriped [here](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/configuring-solrconfig-xml.html#Configuringsolrconfig.xml-JVMSystemProperties).

> Any JVM System properties, usually specified using the `-D` flag when starting the JVM, can be used as variables in any XML configuration file in Solr.

> In general, any Java system property that you want to set can be passed through the bin/solr script using the standard `-Dproperty=value` syntax. Alternatively, you can add common system properties to the SOLR_OPTS environment variable defined in the Solr include file (`bin/solr.in.sh` or `bin/solr.in.cmd`)

So you actually don't need to write your own Dockerfile but just use the solr image and set the environment variable `SOLR_OPTS` like this

```
SOLR_OPTS="-Ddataimporter.request.db_url=$DB_URL -Ddataimporter.request.db_user=$DB_USER -Ddataimporter.request.db_pass=$DB_PASSWORD"
```